# Regex replace exactly 2 backslashes by 3

Tags: php, regex

I have a string where 2 backslashes must become 3 backslashes. With all the escaping of backslashes, I can't do it and nothing's working.

For example:

- `aaaaa\\aaaaa` must become `aaaaa\\\aaaaa`
- `aaaaa\\\aaaaa` STAYS `aaaaa\\\aaaaa` (2 backslashes in a row must not be detected)

I managed this, which works in regex101.com:

```
(\\\\)([^\\])
```

so in php, it would be:

```
preg_replace('/(\\\\)([^\\])/', '\\\$2', $bob);
```

But php gives me this error message:

```
preg_replace(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 10
```

So I don't know if it's a bug of PHP, but I need another way of doing this and I can't find the solution on google.

Comment: As well as escaping in the regex, are you also escaping in the PHP string?

Comment: Incidentally, rather than including `$2` in the replace, you can simply use `(?<!\\)(\\{2})(?!\\)` to only capture the two backslash characters and replace with `\\\` (or, in

Comment: Thanks for your comments Adrian. Yes I am escaping in the PHP string as well, or rather, the encode functions were doing it. Anyway, all is good now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?<!\x5C)\x5C{2}(?!\x5C)
```

Backslashes can be a real nightmare here. It's better to use the ASCII code of the backslash right into the regex.

**Sample code:**

```
define('THREE_SLASHES', preg_quote('\\\\\\'));
define('RE_TWO_SLASHES_ONLY', '~(?<!\x5c)\x5c{2}(?!\x5c)~');

$test='aaaaa\\\\aaaaa';
echo preg_replace(RE_TWO_SLASHES_ONLY, THREE_SLASHES, $test) . '<br>';

$test='aaaaa\\\\\\aaaaa';
echo preg_replace(RE_TWO_SLASHES_ONLY, THREE_SLASHES, $test) . '<br>';
```

**Output**

```
aaaaa\\\aaaaa
aaaaa\\\aaaaa
```

Comment: You'll need brackets around the `\\{2}` to capture the backslashes for the replace to work.

Comment: @AdrianWragg In the end, I choose to use the ASCII code.

Answer (score 2):

You might like to take advantage of [`preg_quote`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) here:

```
$in1 = <<<'EOD'
aaaaa\\aaaaa
EOD;
$in2 = <<<'EOD'
aaaaa\\\aaaaa
EOD;

echo "input 1: $in1";
echo "input 2: $in2";

$q = preg_quote('\\','/');

echo "output 1: " . preg_replace("/(?<!$q)$q$q(?!$q)/", "$q$q$q", $in1);
echo "output 2: " . preg_replace("/(?<!$q)$q$q(?!$q)/", "$q$q$q", $in2);
```

I used a [nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) (available since PHP 5.3.0) to define the input string so that it can be seen exactly as it looks. No parsing is done inside a nowdoc.

`$q` is now an escaped single backslash that can be used in `preg_replace` wherever you wanted to use a literal `\` before.

The regular expression uses negative lookbehind `(?<!$q)` and negative lookahead `(?!$q)` to ensure that the two slashes in the middle aren't preceded or followed by a slash.

Output:

```
input 1: aaaaa\\aaaaa
input 2: aaaaa\\\aaaaa
output 1: aaaaa\\\aaaaa
output 2: aaaaa\\\aaaaa
```

`preg_quote` is normally used for variables longer than one character, so might be seen as overkill here. Instead of using it, you could define `$q = '\\\\';` (two string-escaped backslashes) and that would achieve the same outcome.

Comment: I used the other solution, but thanks for your answer too, did not know about the preg_quote and will use it so much in the future!

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper no problem, glad you got it sorted. `preg_quote` is particularly useful when you don't know exactly what a variable will contain. I just used it here as it means that you don't need to jump through so many hoops.